# Wrap existing link from HTML around other images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to clone an existing link with class="link" and wrap it around each img in the div "wrap"? Suppose we don't know the link so we can't just use this method:

```
$('#wrap img').wrap('<a href="http://foo.com"></a>');
```

HTML:

```
<a href="http://foo.com" class="link">
    <img/>
</a>
<div id="wrap">
    <img class="img" />
    <img class="img" />        
    <img class="img" />
</div>
```

Result:

```
<a href="http://foo.com" class="link">
    <img/>
</a>
<div id="wrap">
      <a href="http://foo.com" class="link"><img class="img" /></a>
      <a href="http://foo.com" class="link"><img class="img" /></a>    
      <a href="http://foo.com" class="link"><img class="img" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `outerHTML` property:

```
var link = $('.link').clone().empty().prop('outerHTML');
$('#wrap img').wrap(link);
```

Comment: `$('.link').clone().empty()` is enough.

Comment: @dfsq That will work too, jQuery clones the object in that case. Since the original snippet had used a string I used `outerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
var anchor = $(".link");
anchor.html('');
$("#wrap img").wrap(anchor);
```

Comment: I tested, using slightly different hmtl: it removed the original img?

Comment: Yes, it removes the original image inside the anchor before wrapping the new images.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try this single line:

```
$('#wrap img').wrap('<a href="' + $('a.link').prop('href') + '">');
```

To clone the element without children:

```
$('#wrap img').wrap($('a.link').clone().empty());
```

Comment: Works. Downside is it won't take the rel="nofollow" target="_blank" with it, but maybe usefull for others.

Comment: Updated answer may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Image dimensions in  then created this  is called into the picture if the picture is not loaded error image is shown.

> 

```
<div id="hekimResimMini"><img src="" id="imgHekimResim" alt="" width="40" height="55" ></div>
```

```
    $('#imgHekimResim').load(function(){})
    .attr("src", "./personelResimi.jpeg?kurSicNo="+lcd.list[x].DOKTORID)
    .error(function() { 
        var thisImg = this;
        if ( $.browser.msie ) {
           setTimeout(function() {
              if ( ! thisImg.complete ) {
                 $(thisImg).attr('src', '../../images/error.png');
                 $(thisImg).css('width','40').css('height','27').css('margin-top','14px').css('margin-bottom','14px');
              }
           },250);
        } else {
           $(this).attr('src', '../../images/error.png');
           $(thisImg).css('width','40').css('height','27').css('margin-top','14px').css('margin-bottom','14px');
        }
    });
```